# What is this menu called in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, menu, windows-phone-8.1

Recently Tapatalk updated their app and a new menu appeared, which I haven't seen before.

Does anyone know what this menu is called?

There is an image in the top left corner which is 3 orange horizontal lines, when you press on it a menu pops out from the left.

I am trying to write my own app and wanted to use this.

I have seen it in a few apps now.

I would upload an image but I am unable to at the moment

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see in the app screenshots, this is a quite typical menu which slides in from the left in many Windows Phone apps these days. It can also be seen in Facebook, for example.

There is a good blog post explaining how to implement that written by Dan Ardelean:

[Add side menus to an Windows Phone application (similar to the Facebook app)](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html)

It comes down to using gestures (or button click) to bring a part of the app into view.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a Flipview with 3 pages (FlipViewItems), it would be almost the same as the Facebook app